# Is there a performance difference between searching strings vs ints?

Tags: android, performance

I have an array of items each having a unique id.

The unique id is an `int` in the database and passed in as a `JSONArray` of `JSONObjects` using an API.

Is it better to use the unique id as a `String` or convert it to an `int` when looping through the `JSONArray` and searching for the unique id?

Comment: Lots of missing information here. If the elements are already strings, converting each one for an integer comparison is going to be slow. If they are already integers, leave them as integers. Also, your post suggests that you're looking for a specific ID? Can they be passed as a Map object instead, that will speed up your search (although if they are already in a list, no reason to convert to a hash first.)
Basically, the performance is in the intention, which is missing here?

Answer (score 0):

`Int`s are generally faster than `String`s, but I'd be surprised if it makes a noticeable difference...  if your server API is passing back enough objects for it to make a difference, then I'd guess that the JSON object would be so large that it'd deserialization time would dwarf the searching time...